# How to divide screen evenly in 3?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm already using this calculation:

```
size = act.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth()/3;

int dip = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(
                 TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                 size,
                 r.getDisplayMetrics()
          );
```

However, my images are way too big. What do I need to do?

Comment: Is a `LinearLayout` and the `weight` attribute not an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way would be to the layout weight when defining the your XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/example" 
        weight="1" />

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/example" 
        weight="1" />

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/example" 
        weight="1" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

You can also use the ScaleType property to change how the image is scaled, hope this helps!